# ApexChart TypeError: "c is undefined" when update chart

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

I started using ApexChart and it worked fine to create the chart, but it's returning a error "c is undefined" when I try to update the chart.

How I create the chart is below. dates is an array with some dates and values an array with numbers

```
var options = {
    chart: {
        height: 350,
        type: 'area',
        zoom: {
            enabled: false
        }
    },
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
    },
    stroke: {
        curve: 'straight'
    },
    series: [{
        name: "Sales",
        data: values
    }],
    title: {
        text: 'Number os sales',
        align: 'left'
    },
    labels: dates,
    xaxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
    },
    yaxis: {
        opposite: true
    },
    legend: {
        horizontalAlign: 'left'
    }
}
var chart = new ApexCharts(
    document.querySelector("#salesChart"),
    options
)
if (document.getElementById('salesChart')) {
    chart.render();
}
```

Then, I try to update the chart by:

```
// Update label
ApexCharts.exec('salesChart', 'updateOptions', {
    xaxis: {
        labels: dates
    }
}, false, true)
// Update values
ApexCharts.exec('salesChart', 'updateSeries', [{
    data: values
}], true);
```

The update above is called when I set a new values for the arrays dates and values.
It's returning the error:

```
TypeError: "c is undefined"
    getChartByID http://myserver.com/assets/js/vendors/charts/apex-charts.js:27013
    exec http://myserver.com/assets/js/vendors/charts/apex-charts.js:26952
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to give an id to the chart in the options

```js
var options = {
  chart: {
    id: 'salesChart'
  }
}
```

The function `ApexCharts.exec` only works when you provide a chart ID.